# convert java object to soap header

Tags: xml, spring, soap, jaxb, apache-camel

i write converter java object to soap header but output hasn't 'ns' prefix

my xml out put is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<AuthHeader>
   <UserName>sample</UserName>
   <Password>sample_password</Password>
</AuthHeader>
```

but the soap header is this:(has 'ns'!!)

```
 <ns:AuthHeader>
    <ns:UserName>sample</ns:UserName>
    <ns:Password>sample_password</ns:Password>
 </ns:AuthHeader>
```

my code is this:

```
    AuthHeader authHeader = new AuthHeader();

    authHeader.setUserName(endDureBean.getUserName());
    authHeader.setPassword(endDureBean.getPassword());

        //Create JAXB Context
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(AuthHeader.class);
        //Create Marshaller
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        //Required formatting??
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        //Print XML String to Console
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        //Write XML to StringWriter
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(authHeader, sw);
        //Verify XML Content
        String xmlContent = sw.toString();
```

Comment: "ns" should be defined by `xmlns:ns=` somewhere in the xml file. Can you please paste the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

i find the solution we should specify 'ns' in the AuthHeader class with @XmlElement:

```
@XmlElement(name = "UserName", namespace = "http:/10.10.10.10:8080/")
protected String userName;
@XmlElement(name = "Password", namespace = "http:/10.10.10.10:8080/")
protected String password;
```

the xml file is like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsample.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns="http:/10.10.10.10:8080/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ns:AuthHeader>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ns:UserName>sample-username</ns:UserName>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ns:Password>sample-password</ns:Password>
      </ns:AuthHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
```